# How do you pass parameters in an Azure DevOps task in a Logic App?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Azure DevOps build / pipeline has this parameter:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: myParameter
```

My account can run the pipeline manually in Azure DevOps and is the same account authenticated in the Logic App.

Logic App:

[image: Azure DevOps task in a Logic App]

It fails to run successfully.

Here's the input for the failed Azure DevOps "Queue a new build" task:

```json
{
    "method": "post",
    "queries": {
        "account": "myOrg",
        "buildDefId": "22"
    },
    "path": "/myProject/_apis/build/builds",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-resource-group-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/visualstudioteamservices"
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "parameters": "{\"myParameter\":\"test\"}",
        "sourceBranch": "develop"
    }
}
```

And the output:

```json
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        // headers
    },
    "body": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nDetails: {\"ClassName\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildRequestValidationFailedException\",\"Message\":\"Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.\",\"Data\":null,\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackIndex\":0,\"ExceptionMethod\":null,\"HResult\":-2146232832,\"Source\":null,\"WatsonBuckets\":null,\"m_logException\":false,\"m_reportException\":false,\"m_errorCode\":0,\"m_logLevel\":\"warning\",\"m_eventId\":3000,\"ValidationResults\":[{\"result\":\"error\",\"message\":\"A value for the 'myParameter' parameter must be provided.\"}]}\r\nclientRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "error": {
            "message": "Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nDetails: {\"ClassName\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildRequestValidationFailedException\",\"Message\":\"Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.\",\"Data\":null,\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackIndex\":0,\"ExceptionMethod\":null,\"HResult\":-2146232832,\"Source\":null,\"WatsonBuckets\":null,\"m_logException\":false,\"m_reportException\":false,\"m_errorCode\":0,\"m_logLevel\":\"warning\",\"m_eventId\":3000,\"ValidationResults\":[{\"result\":\"error\",\"message\":\"A value for the 'myParameter' parameter must be provided.\"}]}"
        },
        "source": "vsts-ae.azconn-ae-002.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }
}
```